# How do I get my old VBScript ASP sendemail to work on Azure?

Tags: asp.net, email, azure, vbscript

I recently migrated my ASP.Net website from a traditional windows 2003 shared server to Azure as a Web App. My VBScript forms which send e-mails to me have stopped working since the migration.  I have tried a few different approaches to get my VBScript email code to work but have had no luck so far.  Part of the problem is that I can't see what the error is.

The first part of my question is: How do I make the ASP.Net errors on my VBScript ASP page visible?   I have set debug='true' in my web.config and I tried to set it on my ASP page (see below) but this hasn't worked.  Currently I just get an 'Internal error 500' page after attempting to send the email with no indication of what went wrong.

Here is the code that sends the e-mail and appears to be the source of the problem.  Can do I change this to work under Azure without rewriting my entire page in C#?

```
<%@ Language=VBScript Debug='true' %>  'Debug=true doesn't work

Set Mailer = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
Mailer.Host = "mail.mydomain.com" ' Specify a valid SMTP server
Mailer.From = Request.Form("AgentEmail") ' Specify sender's address
Mailer.FromName = Request.Form("AgentsName") ' Specify sender's name
Mailer.Port = 587
Mailer.isHTML = True

Mailer.AddAddress "person1@email.com"
Mailer.AddAddress "person2@email.net"
Mailer.AddAddress "person3@email.com"
Mailer.AddAddress Request.Form("AgentEmail")
Mailer.Body = "stuff in my email"


Mailer.Username = "me@emailcom"
Mailer.Password = "123456"
On Error Resume Next
Mailer.Send
If Err <> 0 Then
   Response.Write "Error encountered: " & Err.Description
Else
   Response.Write "Success"
End If
```

This code did work on my old Windows server.  I've left out all of the HTML since that part appears to work just fine.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For future reference, I ended up solving my problem by converting my code to C# and using to smtpClient.  This is the general idea here:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.domain.com", 587);
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(From, "password");
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.Port = 587;
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

try
{
    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(From, "Me");

    smtpClient.Host = "mail.domain.com";

    message.From = fromAddress;
    message.To.Add(To);
    message.Subject = Subject;
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Body = Body;

    smtpClient.Send(message);
    Label_Results.Text = "Email successfully sent.";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ErrorLabel.Text = "<p>Send Email Failed:<p>" + ex.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### For Azure Cloud Services

**Note**: [As of 2023, Azure Cloud Services is now obsolete and will be discontinued shortly](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/cloud-services-retirement-announcement/).

Assuming you're using *Azure Cloud Services*'s *Web Roles* (and **not an Azure VM** or *Azure App Services* (formerly known as *Azure Websites*)), you can use Classic ASP provided you jump through some hoops: https://khailiangtech.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/windows-azure-how-to-enable-classic-asp-support/

1. Open your Cloud Service solution in Visual Studio
2. Open your `.csdef` file.
3. Add this `<WebRole><Startup><Task>` element to your XML:

   ```xml
   <ServiceDefinition>
       <!-- etc -->
       <WebRole>
           <!-- etc -->
           <Startup>
               <!-- etc -->
               <Task commandLine="start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-ASP" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
           </Startup>
           <!-- etc -->
        </WebRole>
       <!-- etc -->
   <ServiceDefinition>
   ```

Windows Azure seems to support CDO (the built-in COM SMTP service) whereas your code is using `Persits.MailSender` - it might be possible to install the `Persits.MailSender` component via the `<ServiceDefinition>` XML - but I don't recommend this because of the 32/64-bit problem.

I suggest changing your script to use CDO instead, here's a reference: http://theholmesoffice.com/using-sendgrid-with-classic-asp-to-send-emails/ (the page is for using SendGrid's SMTP server, but you can use any SMTP server (just don't use port 25).

### For Azure App Services (Azure Websites)

[According to the Azure Blog, *Azure App Services* does not support Classic ASP anymore, but it can work in a Docker-based application](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-migration-and/migrating-active-server-pages-applications-to-azure-app-services/ba-p/3273816) - [based on this Docker template on GitHub](https://github.com/jometzg/classicaspdocker).

The amount of code involved is too long to post to this SO answer, unfortunately.

Comment: That sounds like the answer I'm looking for.  I'll try CDO and give you the check if that works out :)

Comment: @AlanMoore is CDO still supported, did you end up getting it to work from that link? Curious because I'm trying to accomplish the same goal

Comment: @Acoustic77 I see I never did come back to this question!  No I didn't end up using CDO.  I ended up using SmtpClient.

Comment: Any chance you could help someone else trying to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: The link in this answer is now dead, showing the importance of linking but *also* providing the solution.

Comment: @SteveOwen The link works for me right now - but I'll integrate it into my answer for posterity.

Comment: @SteveOwen I just realised the khailiangtech blog article I linked-to is actually for (the now discontinued) _Azure Cloud Service Web Roles_ and not _Azure App Services_ (aka _Azure Websites_).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to instantiate an object from a DLL that is not installed: `Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")`

You can't install any external COM object when using Web Apps.  One option is to use a Virtual Machine and install your COM DLL.

Comment: That sounds like a possible solution, but I'm not sure I want to go that route.  Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try the CDO first and if that doesn't work out I'll take a look at this option.